# mvc6 model binder not picking untagged JSON

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to receive a JSON in a MVC6 controller. I see my function being triggered when debugging, but the param is always null.

The JSON is like this (it comes from an external software, so I can't change it. Also notice the ContentType    is "application/w-xxx-form-urlencoded"):

```
["String1","String2",["StringInAList1","StringInAList2",...]]
```

My code looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public void ReceiveJson([FromBody] MyJson json)
{
    //stuff
}

public class MyJson
{
    public string string1 { get; set; }
    public string string2 { get; set; }
    public List<string> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Any ideas of what's wrong here?

Comment: cannot give you any help if you don't show us how the data is being sent to the controller

Comment: I don't have that much info either, this is all I've got (in the first post) : http://forums.cryptozoic.com/showthread.php?t=40975

Comment: That' not a JSON object, it's a polymorphic array (some entries are strings, some are arrays of strings).  Which JSON serializer (`DataContractJsonSerializer`, json.net, `JavaScriptSerializer`) are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, that JSON is an array, not an object.  A JSON object would look like this

> ```
> {
>     "MessageName": "String1", 
>     "UserName": "String2", 
>     "AdditionalData": ["StringInAList1","StringInAList2",...] 
> }
> ```

Since non-enumerable c# classes are mapped to JSON objects, asp.net isn't going to be able to deserialize that JSON to your class by default.

Secondly, going by the documentation [here](http://forums.cryptozoic.com/showthread.php?t=40975), `AdditionalData` can be any array of strings or nested arrays of the same type, not just a simple array of strings, for instance:

> ```
> ["GameEnded","Risterral",[["Risterral", "Won"],["PlayerName2", "Lost"]]]
> ```

A simple `List<string> Data` won't be able to represent this.

Since [asp.net uses Json.NET by default for JSON serialization](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization), the easiest way to represent such a polymorphic array is as a [`JArray`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm), which can represent any JSON array in memory.  You will also need a [custom `JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) for the top level object.  Thus:

```
public enum HexRequestType
{
    Unknown,
    Login,
    Logout,
    SaveDeck,
    DraftPack,
    DraftCardPicked,
    GameStarted,
    GameEnded,
    Collection,
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(HexRequestConverter))]
public class HexRequest
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public HexRequestType RequestType
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(MessageName))
                return HexRequestType.Unknown;
            if (MessageName.Equals("DaraftCardPicked", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                return HexRequestType.DraftCardPicked;
            try
            {
                return (HexRequestType)Enum.Parse(typeof(HexRequestType), MessageName, true);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Unknown request " + MessageName);
                return HexRequestType.Unknown;
            }
        }
    }

    public string MessageName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public JArray AdditionalData { get; set; }
}

public class HexRequestConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(HexRequest);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var array = JToken.Load(reader) as JArray;
        if (array == null)
            return existingValue;
        var request = existingValue as HexRequest ?? new HexRequest();
        request.MessageName = (array.Count > 0 ? (string)array[0] : null);
        request.UserName = (array.Count > 1 ? (string)array[1] : null);
        request.AdditionalData = (JArray)(array.Count > 2 ? array[2] : null) ?? new JArray();
        if (array.Count > 3)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("array too large");
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
        return request;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var request = (HexRequest)value;
        var list = new List<object> { request.MessageName, request.UserName, request.AdditionalData };
        serializer.Serialize(writer, list);
    }
}
```

Having done that, you can use Linq and [Linq-to-JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CreateJsonManually.htm) to manually extract the expected data, for instance:

```
            switch (request.RequestType)
            {
                case HexRequestType.GameEnded:
                    {
                        // ["GameEnded","Risterral",[["Risterral", "Won"],["PlayerName2", "Lost"]]]
                        var results = request.AdditionalData.OfType<JArray>().Select(a => new { Player = (string)a[0], Result = (string)a[1] }).ToList();
                        Debug.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results));
                        // Outputs [{"Player":"Risterral","Result":"Won"},{"Player":"PlayerName2","Result":"Lost"}]
                    }
                    break;

                // Other cases as needed

                default:
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: First, thanks for writing such a detailed answer, but I'm new to mvc and I'm not following :S
What I'm supposed to put in my controller then? Because right now I can't even get the raw json string. When debugging I see the Request.ContentLength changing as the different events fire, but I don't see the data anywhere.

Comment: @Plaga = try here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api or here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OneASPNETMakingJSONWebAPIsWithASPNETMVC4BetaAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx

Comment: Yeah, I had already found those when I was looking for examples of how to construct a web api, but I feel like I'm missing something really basic here.
If I want to get just the JArray as an input to the controller method, how should I do it? Because
[HttpPost]
public void ReceiveJson([FromBody] JArray json) is not doing the trick.

Comment: BTW, the one I've been following is this one: http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/create-a-web-api-with-mvc-6

Comment: A little late, but I think one issue with what you posted is that in MVC6, [FromBody] looks for the data to be in the body of the request, and not in the form data. If your content type is "application/w-xxx-form-urlencoded", it will ignore the body of the request by default. https://lbadri.wordpress.com/2014/11/23/web-api-model-binding-in-asp-net-mvc-6-asp-net-5/ has a lot of great scenarios that should show you how to structure your posts and controllers to get what you're looking for.